# Cannot add Event Listener in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

When I pass a function defined in an object as an event function in an event listener, the function doesn't work. For reference, here's the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <button id='hi'>Hi</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's the JavaScript code (script.js):

```
var test = {
  arr: [1,2,3],
  hello: function() {
    console.log(this.arr.length);
  }
};

var a = document.getElementById('hi');
a.addEventListener('click', test.hello);
```

The function `hello` from the object `test` doesn't get executed when button is clicked, showing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.hello (script.js:6)
```

Are callback functions passed differently when they are properties of an object? Or this is due to some other issue relating to event listening?